# Terminate thread instantly in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, terminate, abort

I'm currently writing a program that runs multiple threads all trying to send requests to a web server. I need a way in which I can terminate all the threads, I've tried using both `Thread.Abort` and a flag, but both seem to take forever to terminate all the threads I'm running and `Thread.Abort` probably doesn't event work. First I gather all the thread objects into a `List<Thread>`:

```
            Thread thread = new Thread(...);
            thread.IsBackground = true; //Terminate thread when application is shutdown
            checkerThread.Start();
            threadList.Add(thread); //List to hold all thread objects.
```

So the first method I've tried is to just try to force the thread to abort by injecting an exception via `Thread.Abort`.

```
foreach(Thread thr in threadList)
   thr.Abort();
```

As  said above this just seems to hang forever and not do anything. Using a flag however does work, the only drawback being is that it take forever.

```
stopped = true; //Boolean flag, threads are on a while loop that check it.

while (threadsAreRunning()) //Function that checks if there any live threads in the list, does not continue until all threads are dead.
{
  Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

The reason this flag does not work seems to be a `getRequestStream()` function from `HttpWebRequest` running in my threads that hangs for a long time, I have set every possible timeout I can but this bug seems to persist, leading me to believe that the problem lies with the `getRequestStream()` function iteself.

Now my question is why doesn't `Thread.Abort` work and hang when trying to terminate these threads? And is there some other way in which I can terminate a thread?

Please excuse any grammar or spelling mistakes, English in not my first language.

Thanks to everyone that responds to this thread.

Comment: You are asking how to stop a thread, but what you want is to cancel an HttpWebRequest. https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=cancel+HttpWebRequest Also: https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=thread.abort+evil

Comment: _HttpWebRequest's Timeout_ is set but it hangs at _GetRequestStream()_ ? Set a breakpoint at that line and debug.

Comment: You cannot abort a thread that's buried deep inside an operating system call.  Thread.Abort() is a bad solution for many reasons, including it not actually being able to abort a thread :)  Use HttpWebRequest.Abort() instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately aborting the `HttpWebRequest` does not do anything in my case as the threads that hang do so while attempting to get a request stream, disregarding the timeout I have set. This is the reason I asked how I can just force the threads to terminate as nothing else seems to work, including `Thread.Abort`.